# "avahi-daemon[1540]: server.c: Packet too short or invalid while reading response record. (Maybe a UTF-8 problem?)"

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, daemon, avahi, packet

We are developing an application in Java for our internal project.
Apache-Tomcat-7.0.57 is running on a Linux machine (Red Hat 4.4.6-4). But it  throws an error `avahi-daemon[1540]: server.c: Packet too short or invalid while reading response record. (Maybe a UTF-8 problem?)` on the server every 30 minutes in the `/var/log/messages` file. Every day we need to restart Apache-Tomcat for login in order to run application.

I'd like to know the cause for this and what I can do to avoid that.

Comment: How does you application interact with avahi?

Comment: sorry for the delay. i am System admin and new to Linux .First page is login page, when we submit user id and  password. It is throwing an error saying that "the page IPaddress:8080 says invalid user id or password"
After restarting Apache-Tomcat-7.0.57, it is accepting user id and password. It works fine and allowing to visit remaining pages without any error but every day we need to restart Apache-Tomcat .

Comment: Unless you have something on your server that depends on service auto-discovery, then you don't need avahi-daemon and you can disable it.

Avahi is a zeroconf implementation, ie. it'll discover services in your network, such as printers, media servers, etc and do hostname to ip resolution if it finds any. The error message tells you a network device fails to provide a valid record for avahi, but it's very unlikely it has anything to do with Tomcat requiring a restart. Better check catalina.log for that.

Since it's been sometime, have you figure this out? You can close this topic then.